# SQL how to Select count of records with the same value in column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have a table set up essentially like this:

```
Question | Category
=========|=========
Who?     |Vague
What?    |Vague
When?    |Specific
Why?     |Specific
How?     |Specific
```

I want to select all of the questions, but I also want to return the amount of entries that are in the same category as the entry that is currently being selected, like this:

```
Question | Category | Count
=========|==========|======
Who?     |Vague     |2
What?    |Vague     |2
When?    |Specific  |3
Why?     |Specific  |3
How?     |Specific  |3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Oracle. Sorry, noob mistake of putting both as tags.

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle (and most other databases), you simply use analytic functions:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by category) as cnt
from t;
```

In MySQL, a correlated subquery is probably the best approach:

```
select t.*, (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.category = t.category) as cnt
from t;
```

Comment: I partitioned it by category and it works like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @judgebeanhead . . . That would be the column to use, based on the question.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.Question, a.Category, count(*)
From table a
   join table b 
      on b.Category = a.Category  
Group By a.Question, a.Category
```